# Error when connecting to Named Instance as a Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server, multiple-instances

I have a MS SQL2008 server running a root instance and a named instances.

> SQL001\.
>
> SQL001\Pilgrim

When I connected to **SQL001\Pilgrim** I can set-up a link to the default instance **SQL001\.** no problem, but when I connect to the Default Instance **SQL001\.** and try to add a link to the named instance **SLQ001\Pilgrim** I get the error below.

This was working before I rebooted the server nearly a month ago but all services are running. I have tried restarting them.

The server in Windows 2008 R2 64bit and MSSQL is 2008. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on the server itself and the firewall is off.

The web applications and clients that use both instances are working perfectly.

[image: SQL Error: Encryption not supported on the client]

Comment: To clarify - You  CAN connect locally through SSMS on the server itself, right? The issue is that you can't create a linked server on that server to an instance on the same server? Can you go the other direction with the linked server?

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying, been ill. Yes I can connect directly to either instance through SSMS. When connected to the named instance I CAN create a linked server connection to the default instance. When connected to the default instance I CAN'T create a linked server connection to the named instance.

Comment: Can you connect to the named instance via SSMS remotely from your laptop or another machine?

Comment: Yes, it is just the linked server connection from the default instance that is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start out by verifying:

A.) Ensure Named Pipes and TCP/IP are both enabled for the named instance. (SQL Server Configuration Manager --> Server Network Config --> Protocols  --> Verify TCP/IP, Named Pipes are enabled

B.) SQL Server Browser service is enabled and running

Comment: Named Pipes were disabled on the default instance so I am turning them on. Says service needs to be restarted so I will have to do that out of hours and let you know. Ta.

Comment: Pretty sure that's your issue. Sounds good, looking forward to results after restart.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked. Sorry for delay in getting back to you.